# Use CMS capabilities of joomla for a custom database table

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, phpmyadmin

I would want to have the CMS capabilities (or at least the basic functionalities like CRUD) for my custom db table. Is there a way to do this. Migration is not an option for me since there are other applications that use this table.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Sure, you can connect anything you want to Joomla, but we're going to need a lot more detail. What are you trying to accomplish? What is stored in the table? Is the table data being included on a site or is the site built for the table data?

Answer (score 0):

Two choices spring to mind for quickly build 'basic' components such as you describe here.

JFooBar component - is a component you install into Joomla 1.7 that facilitates building components that you then package up:
https://github.com/Niambie/jfoobar

Alternatively there is an online tool that does a similar job:
http://www.j-cook.pro

I've only played with these tools - but have a couple of projects that need something simple knocking together and will be trying them out on 'real world' projects shortly.